# Kubernetes - Error pulling from a private docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a scala application. I have pushed the docker image at a private registry. Now, as I understand I need to create a secret to pull the image from a private repository using a yaml file.

I have created a secret using the following command :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-username=token --docker-password=<private repo password> --docker-email=<email id which I use to access the private repo>
```

This successfully creates a secret.

The image is now pushed to 
The image name is "imagecheck", and repo name is "repocheck".
Now, when I try to pull the image from my yaml file, it gives an error saying

> Failed to pull image "abc.somerepo.com/repocheck/imagecheck:latest": image pull failed for abc.somerepo.com/repocheck/imagecheck:latest, this may be because there are no credentials on this request

This is my yaml file :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: onlinescoring
spec:
  replicas: 4 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  strategy: 
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: online1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cont1
        image: abc.somerepo.com/repocheck/imagecheck:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 32014
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
```

I am able to pull the image from my terminal. please guide as to how to resolve the error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the secret and the recreate using:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=token --docker-password=<private repo password> --docker-email=<email id which I use to access the private repo>
```

Replace `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER` with private registry url.

Default value: `https://index.docker.io/v1/`

Comment: note : if you have a $ in your password, you must escape it by using \$